# How do application context and url-pattern interact?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, web.xml

I am using IntelliJ to spin-up a Tomcat 9 server with a Jersey servlet inside, to respond to REST requests.

When I use IntelliJ's deployment Run/Debug Configurations > Deployment tab I can specify the application context, the base of all the URLs for this server (after `domain:port`).

When I set the application conetext to `/COMP/rest` and set the `web.xml` `<servlet-mapping><url-pattern>` to `/*` I can access all my routes **except** the `web.xml` specified `<error-page>` does not work for the corresponding errors [it's as though Tomcat can't find the location of the page because it's not even returning a stock Tomcat error page but a fully blank 404, even when the error code was a 500].

As soon as I switch the application context to  `/COMP` and the `<url-pattern>` to `/rest/*`, I can see all routes and the **error pages work**.

***Why?***

*Update:* An application context of`/` and a `<url-pattern>` of`/COMP/rest/*` also works for all routes and the error pages.

*Update 2*: So I'm forcing a 500 and when it works it detects the 500 and serves my 500 page but when it's not working it's as though it throws the 500, looks for my 500 page, can't find it, and then throws the 404 without the correct Tomcat 404 page being sent.

Comment: ..probably: because "error pages" are resolved relatively to "application context(root)" ...and the error page is not found/replaced by tomcat's default (in the first case)...and correct (in the latter case)(!?)

Comment: @xerx593, so then how do I make the first case work? How do I specify the proper `<location>` of the error page?

Comment: in the simplest case (error page is a static html file?): or move the (error) page (file) ..into correct folder (...i.e. -> `rest`), or change the value of  `<error-page/>` (to the (relatively) correct folder) ...what is the actual (constant in both cases) value of `error-page` ?

Comment: the `<location>` of the error page (when it works) is `/general-error.html`

Comment: changing it to `/rest/general-error.html` does not work either

Comment: pfff, the "Update:"'s confusing me also completely! :)

Comment: but "...a fully blank 404, even when the error code was a 500" could also be a hint ...what if you are wrong, and *it is* 404 (not found ..maybe even the error page)!?

Comment: a 404 can *easily* occur, when you "miss"/don't know your context path...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207928/discussion-between-zac-taylor-and-xerx593).

Comment: Application context that you specify - is the root of the web application. It is starting url by which your application will accept the requests. If you any url pattern starts with this path.- it will hit your application and it will be handling this request. Url pattern for servlet mapping is the pattern that will route corresponding path to corresponding servlet.

Comment: @Andrey, thank you for the concise explanations but that's exactly why I don't understand the behaviour I'm observing. Why would there be a difference in the pages served when I make the changes I mentioned in the question.